# tensorflow toco command for .tflite

Tags: tensorflow, toco

I am following the steps at [TFLite Android](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets-2-tflite/#0)

I am not able to use the toco command and so cannot generate: "optimized_graph.lite"

Here is the command that I use :

```
    IMAGE_SIZE=224
toco \
  --graph_def_file=tf_files/retrained_graph.pb \
  --output_file=tf_files/optimized_graph.lite \
  --input_format=TENSORFLOW_GRAPHDEF \
  --output_format=TFLITE \
  --input_shape=1,${IMAGE_SIZE},${IMAGE_SIZE},3 \
  --input_array=input \
  --output_array=final_result \
  --inference_type=FLOAT \
  --input_data_type=FLOAT
```

And the error is:

F tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/toco.cc:46] Check failed: parsed_toco_flags.input_file.specified() Missing required flag: input_file

I have followed the instructions carefully, on Mac OS, and tensorflow version is 1.7

Comment: I got exactly the same error at the same step in TFLite Android codelab.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not able to try your solution. I tried to upgrade my tensorflow and now I am getting other strange errors. I hope I can resolve that and try your solution

Answer (score 3):

When I ran

```
toco --help
```

I saw no `--graph_def_file` in the options of this command. 
Instead I found `--input_file`, and its meaning is
*Input file (model of any supported format). For Protobuf formats, both text and binary are supported regardless of file extension.*

After I replaced `--graph_def_file` with `--input_file`, the command worked and I got an optimized_graph.lite file.

Below is the complete command.

```
toco \
  --input_file=tf_files/retrained_graph.pb \
  --output_file=tf_files/optimized_graph.lite \
  --input_format=TENSORFLOW_GRAPHDEF \
  --output_format=TFLITE \
  --input_shape=1,${IMAGE_SIZE},${IMAGE_SIZE},3 \
  --input_array=input \
  --output_array=final_result \
  --inference_type=FLOAT \
  --input_data_type=FLOAT
```

Comment: Looking long for the solution. Thanks Man.